# ProposalResponsePayloads do not match - ERC-1155 Chaincode / fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I follow [ERC-1155 chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-erc-1155) example for Fabric. When I run the [BatchTransferFrom](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-erc-1155#batchtransferfrom) part. It sometimes gives error and sometimes runs successfully. I cannot understand why it fails sometimes. Is this error normal when invoking chaincode functions on Fabric?

The error is:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction: ProposalResponsePayloads do not match - proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200 > payload: ...
```

When I call the command using Fabric Node SDK API, it gives the following error:

```
2021-08-30T09:59:41.794Z - error: [DiscoveryHandler]: compareProposalResponseResults[undefined] - read/writes result sets do not match index=1
2021-08-30T09:59:41.794Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=undefined, status=grpc, message=Peer endorsements do not match
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the problem. Iterating maps in Go is not deterministic and the function `BatchTransferFrom` uses maps. The map is iterated in different orders in different peers and as a result, this causes the proposals to be different.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a transaction, all the responses from different endorsements in the transaction must match.

For any reason, this is not happening with your proposals. Different peers return different responses.

I don't know about that specific chaincode, but common causes are:

- Using pseudo-random values.
- Using current timestamps instead of the ones from transaction or block.
- Serializing a JSON in an undeterministic way, so that it results in different strings, as elements have been serialized in different order.
- Etc.